# Getting HTTP ERROR 405 when trying to submit simple form php atom

Tags: php, html, atom-editor

To whom it may concern,

I am recently learning HTML, CSS, JS and now PHP as well. I am working in Atom and use atom-live-server to watch what I am doing. I follow the course on W3schools on PHP and even when I copy their code, I receive an error in Google Chrome (HTTP ERROR 405). After investigating the issue for a while I cannot find a solution. I have added a PHP-server to atom and have set the right path. I will attach the relevant code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" src = "stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="passwords.php" method = "post">
      <input type = "text" name = "Username" placeholder = "Username" required>
      <input type = "password" name = "Password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And the php file:

```
<html>
<body>
  <? php echo $_POST["Username"]; ?>
  <? php echo $_POST["Password"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you run simple echo "hello world" in your php server ?

Comment: What kind of HTTP server are you using?

Comment: Remove unnecessary spaces please.

Comment: @MohammedBilal I just tried that, but I don't think the PHP in the file is the problem. No matter what code I insert, when submitting the form the page that opens just returns an error.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov I am not sure how to even find that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured out was what happening. First of all I tried installing XAMPP and the Apache and mySQL server (which turned out not to be the solution and was basically useless). But as I was starting these servers I found out that the ports that were reserved for these servers were blocked for some reason (probably by McAffee Livesafe). This made me try to change the port in the built-in PHP-server in Atom. I changed it from 8000 to 8081. Next when I tried to set my PHP-server to my index.php file, Windows prompted me if I would allow the PHP-server at the relevant port. I obviously did. After this the PHP-code that I had written in passwords.php worked!

**Additional Remark**
For anyone running into the same problem: for some reason the atom-live-server in Atom will not function well with the PHP file. Starting such a server is useless if you use any PHP file, as you will get the same error as I got. So it comes down to refreshing the page.

**Thanks to everyone trying to help me with my problem! Eventhough it might not have brought me the final solution, it still helped me lots.**

Comment: I suggest you to use Netbeans IDE or Eclipse IDE for php for proper development. These hippie text editors are basically focused on JavaScript development with a little bit of php and stuff like that.

Comment: @MohammedBilal Thanks for the tip. I will certainly look into that. I already use eclipse for java.

Answer (score 0):

I never knew Atom had a php server so I just tried it out...

But I must state up front that I am not getting your http 405 Error.

**My Setup of your files**
I set up your main file as index.php and your passwords.php as is.

From ATOM, I right clicked on index.php and selected "PHP Server Here" which launched the Chrome Browser with the URL `http://localhost:8000/index.php`.
So that displayed the Form... and then filling it in and clicking the submit button, takes me to `http://localhost:8000/passwords.php`

BUT you have another issue as you have spaces in your PHP opening Tags.

`<? php` should be `<?php`

So your code...

```
<html>
<body>
  <? php echo $_POST["Username"]; ?>
  <? php echo $_POST["Password"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Should be like

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php echo $_POST["Username"]; ?>
  <?php echo $_POST["Password"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

An Alternative to using `<?php echo` is `<?=`

**As an aside for Debugging?**

To detect errors.
In your main file you can use.

```
<?php
// Enable FULL Error Reporting on the screen
// ONLY USE IN DEVELOPMENT
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**NOTE:** It appears that it isn't too fussed about `<? php` and does not see it as an error as such as it's not detected as being valid php code. But it's good for all other PHP issues.

If you view your HTML Source in your Browser you will see it outputting...

**HTML Source Code from Browser**

```
<html>
<body>
  <? php echo $_POST["Username"]; ?>
  <? php echo $_POST["Password"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Viewing array values

Using `var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);` will display all Values of an Array, in this case the global $_POST array. Just so you can see what is being posted, if you ever need it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and comprehensive reply. This was my first post to stackoverflow and I am pleasantly surprised to receive help this quick. Now I tried your suggestion but when I change the file with a php extension and set the PHP-server to index.php I get a tab with (on the tab) "listing directory /" and it just lists the files saved in my folder. I also changed the spacing, so thank you for that tip!

Comment: @NielsvandenHeuvel So let's go back a step... What is your actual file structure? What are you seeing in the "directly listing" ?

Comment: @Niels van den Heuvel you dont even need a password.php file.
post the password in the same index file first see if your form is working or not.

Delete everything and copy and paste a working example from W3Schools on basic php. if that still didnt work then the problem is in your file structure. this shouldn't take that long to print a post variable. Error 403 means its a client side error you are sending or receiving a bad formatted request.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am assuming you mean the "listing directory /". It shows me all the files in the folder, like local Images that I use on the websites or the javascript file that I linked etc. If I click on the files it downloads the clicked file.

Comment: @MohammedBilal So I tried creating a new project/folder and added only a basic.php file to this. I started with the most basic example from W3Schools which is the "Hello World!" example: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
` This gave me the listing directory / tab again consisting only of a download link of the basic.php file. I should also add that I am using atom-live-server, but I tried opening it manually and this did not work either.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw  am not sure if you get an notification from my last comment on the thread; but as you can see I solved it. Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: @MohammedBilal I am not sure if you get an notification from my last comment on the thread; but as you can see I solved it. Thank you for your help guys!