# I keep getting a 405 error on form submission

Tags: php, html

I'm currently developing a web application, and I've hit a snag that has left me quite baffled. I've set up a user registration form, and the goal is to store this data in a MySQL database using PHP. However, every time I try to submit the form using Chrome, I'm greeted with an HTTP Error 405, which indicates that the HTTP method I'm using isn't supported. What's even more puzzling is that no data ends up being saved to my database.

To give you a clearer picture, here's the PHP script that I'm using to handle the form submission:
(PHP)

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

if(!empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($userid)) {
  $host = "localhost";
  $dbUsername = "root"; 
  $dbPassword = "";
  $dbname = "phplogin";

  $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
  } else {
    $SELECT = "SELECT userid From register Where userid = ? Limit 1";
    $INSERT = "INSERT Into register (username, password, userid) values(?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

    if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();

      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $userid);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
    } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this userid";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Comp484 Lab 3 </h1>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"></h1>
    <form method="POST" action="lab3.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>userid:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

I thought that perhaps the issue was related to the method I was using to send the form data. So, I tried switching the form's method from POST to GET to see if that would make any difference. Unfortunately, it didn't help, and I'm still faced with the same 405 error.

I've poured over numerous articles and forum posts, but haven't been able to find a solution that works for my specific scenario. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any insights into what might be causing this, I would be immensely grateful for your assistance.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

Comment: 405 error means a problem with the webserver configuration, it's not a PHP problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324763/getting-http-error-405-when-trying-to-submit-simple-form-php-atom

Comment: You're probably not running your code on a proper webserver. Use the php built-in webserver, or Apache, or IIS.

Comment: This problem commonly occurs when people try to use PHP on free, static hosting (such as Github Pages) or when they try to do development on a server designed for client-side work (like VS Code Live Server) instead of using a hosting service / web server that *actually supports PHP*.

Comment: "What's even more puzzling is that no data ends up being saved to my database." — Since the server has said "You are not allowed to make POST requests here" it shouldn't be surprising that the server hasn't executed the PHP and passed the data from the POST request into it.

Answer (score -1):

The 405 error happens when a client attempts to use an HTTP method that is not allowed by the server. Which means maybe you've configured the method in a wrong way, as I saw on your code you want to have the "POST" method

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
```

But you've typed the method in a correct way

```
<form method="POST" action="lab3.php">
```

So I assume there is something wrong with your configuration

[Check your response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptwDR.png)

There is the word "allow". Maybe you don't have that "post" inside your "allow".

Can you please provide me what kind of server that you're running on?